# SSHing github takes too long

Tags: git, github, ssh

Once I run

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I do get the output back

```
Hi V4G4X! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Unfortunately I had to wait **2 minutes 12 seconds** for it.
What might be causing this?

Comment: Why should unwanted traffic be prioritized to run quickly?

Comment: @tripleee But there aren't any other applications that could be using the network at the time.

Comment: The _server_ doesn't want to spend time servicing a request which isn't allowed.

Comment: I doubt the issue is due to the load at the github servers.Forcing a IPv4 connection "fixed" the issue for now. But that's bound to create another issue later.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your environment, OS and Git version.

For instance, in [this ticket](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Slow-SSH-clone-pull-push/qaq-p/953843):

> SSH supports both IPv4 and IPv6 and prefers IPv6 if the DNS retrieves AAAA record, but my ISP doesn't support IPv6, which results in huge delays.
>
> We can solve it in two ways
>
> - Filter out AAAA replies so that we are left with IPv4 address (too much work)
> - Set "`AddressFamily inet`" in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to force IPv4 connection
>
> After changing ssh_config do restart ssh client, on Ubuntu the command is
>
> ```
> sudo service ssh restart"
> ```

Comment: I see the ```AddressFamily inet``` step. But from what I understand, I can only have IPv4 connections now and not IPv6 connections right? Wouldn't that cause problems?

Comment: Again, it depends on your environment, of which I know nothing about. But test it out, just in case.